# External Login to Web Mail

Tags: php, python, email, authentication, roundcube

I was wondering is there anyway I can let people login from a normal PHP page into SquirelMail/Roundcube etc?

So I would have a login lay-out setup and if they fill in their e-mail and password it logs them in to SquirellMail/Roundcube? They must not use the login page of SquirelMail but the one I created.

Is this possible, if yes how?

Comment: create a form with the action set on the roundcube (for example) login script?

Comment: You ought to be able to create a form that submits to an external location.  A couple of issues, though: 1) the external site can prevent this by adding hidden tokens to the page, as is sometimes done to combat cross-site request forgery attacks, and 2) I'm always more comfortable if someone's password for an external site never gets entered on my site -- no one can accuse me of hijacking it, that way.  Looks like Jervelund found a vendor-specific solution, so I'd go with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like what you are requesting: http://squirrelmail.org/wiki/EmbeddedSquirrelMailLogin

Answer (score 1):

## Roundcube

index.php.diff

```
104,105c104,105
<   if ($auth['valid'] && !$auth['abort'] &&
<     $RCMAIL->login($auth['user'], $auth['pass'], $auth['host'], $auth['cookiecheck'])
---
>   if (
>     $RCMAIL->login($auth['user'], $auth['pass'])
308d307
<
```

login.html (to test)

```
<form name="form" action="http://webmail.example.com/" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_task" value="login">
    <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="login">
    <input type="hidden" name="_timezone" id="rcmlogintz" value="_default_">
    <input type="hidden" name="_url" id="rcmloginurl">
    <input name="_user" id="rcmloginuser" size="40" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" type="text">
    <input name="_pass" id="rcmloginpwd" size="40" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" type="password">
    <input type="submit" class="button mainaction" value="Enter" /></p>
</form>
```